# Does nginx support quic?

Tags: nginx, quic, http3

does nginx support quic? if yes how can it be enabled? I have tried some solutions found online but that did not help https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1057.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it does not yet.

However [Cloudflare have released their Nginx patch](https://blog.cloudflare.com/experiment-with-http-3-using-nginx-and-quiche/) for HTTP/3 and QUIC (the soon-to-be standardised IETF QUIC rather than the proprietary original Google QUIC).